# Confused on a Differential Forms Problem

Tags: differential-forms

The problem goes as follows: "Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^k$ a $C^{\infty}$ map. If zero is a regular value of $f$, the set $X = f^{-1}(0)$ is a manifold of dimension $n = N-k$. Show that this manifold has a natural smooth orientation."

The first hint of the problem then states "Let $f = (f_1, \cdots, f_k)$ and let $df_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge df_k = \sum_I f_Idx_I$ summed over the multi-indices which are strictly increasing. Show that for every $p \in X$, $f_I(p) \neq 0$ for some multi-index $I, (i_1, \cdots, i_k), 1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq N$."

I am very confused by multiple parts of this hint. Shouldn't $df_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge df_k = \mbox{det}\left(\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}\right)dx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n$? What is $f_I$ in this case? And how can the index go up through $N$ if there all only $k$ component functions? I am assuming its due to the partials but want to be sure. The book my class is using has a lot of typos, so I am assuming that's what this boils down to. Want to clarify though. Thank you!

Comment: Can you answer the following questions: 1. Why (what theorem) tells you $X$ is a submanifold? 2. What does $0$ being a regular value of $f$ mean? What it its definition? So, what (specifically what linear-algebraic property) does that tell you about $df_1(p),\dots, df_k(p)$ for $p\in X$? 3. What does it mean to have an orientation? So, can you tell what is the purpose of the hint? (It is almost telling you why there's an orientation). Also, regarding your final paragraph, NO. $df_1\wedge \cdots\wedge df_k$ is a $k$-form, but the object you wrote on the right is an $n$-form.

Comment: @peek-a-boo In my book, its theorem 4.1.7, but there is a theorem proven that $X$ is a submanifold. $f$ being a regular value means its a submersion, or $Df_p$ is surjective and thus $df_1(p), \cdots, df_k(p)$ are not all zero. I get all of that. What I'm confused about is then what $df_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge df_k$ is? Specifically, what is $f_I$?

Comment: You made a small mistake: "$df_1(p),\dots, df_k(p)$ are not all zero" is the wrong statement. The correct statement is "$df_1(p),\dots, df_k(p)$" are linearly independent. You should have hopefully seen that wedge product of k many $1$-forms is non-zero if and only if they are linearly independent. Lastly, regarding what the $f_I$ are, I think $f_I$ is an unfortunate choice of notation. Note that $df_1\wedge\cdots\wedge df_k$ is a $k$-form on $\Bbb{R}^N$. Meanwhile, $\{dx^I=dx^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_k}\,:\, \text{$I$ increasing $k$-tuple}\}$ is a basis for $k$-forms in $\Bbb{R}^N$.

Comment: Therefore, the $k$-form $df_1\wedge \cdots\wedge df_k$ can be written as a linear combination of the $dx^I$'s. The $f_I$'s are just the "expansion coefficients". Note that you do not need an explicit formula for these $f_I$'s (which is somewhat messy). You just need to know they exist, and you have to prove they're non-zero (for this, I suggest you look at the problem abstractly and prove the general statement above: a wedge-product of 1-forms is non-zero if and only if they're linearly independent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all $\displaystyle df_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{\partial f_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}dx_{i}\,,j=1,2,...k$

So $\displaystyle df_{1}\wedge df_{2}...\wedge df_{k}=\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{i}}dx_{i}\bigg)\wedge\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x_{i}}dx_{i}\bigg)\wedge\dots\wedge\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{\partial f_{k}}{\partial x_{i}}dx_{i}\bigg)$

So in particular it would have terms like $(\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{i_{1}}}dx_{i_{1}})\wedge(\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x_{i_{2}}}dx_{i_{2}})\wedge\dots\wedge(\frac{\partial f_{k}}{\partial x_{i_{k}}}dx_{i_{k}})$. So when you write them in their unique representation you WILL get the form $\displaystyle\sum_{I}^{\text{increasing}}f_{I}\cdot dx_{I}$.

Now if you do prove that $ df_{1}\wedge df_{2}...\wedge df_{k}$ is a nowhere vanishing on the submanifold then it get's its natural orientation from it.

Here is a complete solution to the problem:-

By the Regular Level Set Theorem you have that $f^{-1}(0)$ is a submanifold of the required codimension.

Now as $0$ is a regular value, we have for every point in the submanifold , the matrix $\bigg[\frac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}\bigg]_{k\times N}$ has full rank $=k$. And hence in particular $\{df_{i}\}_{i=1}^{k}$ is a linearly independent set.

Now it is easy to prove that if $\omega_{1},...,\omega_{k}$ are $1$-forms on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ (with dimension not necessarily $k$) , then $\omega_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\omega_{k}=0$ if and only if $\omega_{1},...,\omega_{k}$ are linearly dependent.

One direction is obvious by just writing $\displaystyle\omega_{k}=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}c_{i}\omega_{i}$ and then expanding the wedge product and using the fact that the $\omega_{i}\wedge\omega_{i}=0$ .

And conversely if they are linearly independent then you extend them to a basis for the dual space $V^*$ and then use the basis to get the corresponding double dual basis for $V^{**}$ and use the canonical identification of the vector space $V$ with it's double dual to get $k$ linearly independent vectors $E_{1},...,E_{k}$ such that $\omega_{i}(E_{j})=\delta_{ij}$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker Delta.

Now it is again an easy excercise to prove that $\omega_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\omega_{k}(v_{1},...,v_{k})=\det(\omega_{i}(v_{j}))$ .

Thus we have $\omega_{1}\wedge\dots\wedge\omega_{k}(E_{1},...,E_{k})=\det(I_{k\times k})=1\neq 0$ and thus $\omega_{1}\wedge\dots\omega_{k}\neq 0$.

Hence using these above results you can conclude as required.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. Thank you!